# Why is the generated Android class called R?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm just curious, who in the world names a class R ? Is there any history behind this convention?

Thanks,
Teja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's just short for Resources.

Comment: Either that, or they're fans of pirates... :-)

Comment: On hindsight, that seems obvious :). But R! Come on!

Comment: @CW: *rimshot*

Haha, well TY, it's definitely easier that way than typing Resources.id.******* each time, so I have no problem with it. :)